# Include a JS file in a React-Native Typescript project

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Basically I am trying to customize a library file written in plain javascript and put it as a local file in a React-Native typescript project, the moment I try to convert the .js file to .ts/.tsx file, it throws a lots of linting issues, so fixing it is bit chaotic so I thought of keeping it as .js file only but I don't want to make any changes in the tsconfig file(i.e., adding jsallow = true), I know their is a way of adding some .d.ts file but not sure will it work or not and if it is, then what would be the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a package named `example`, you can add types in `example.d.ts` using `declare module "example" {}`. There's more detailed information the [Declaration Files Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html).

Comment: it would be good if you can hint me with the exact syntax as I am aware of this one but not sure how to import the file or point to that file within the application

Comment: I'd need more information about what you're importing and how, as TypeScript has different syntaxes for different types of modules that aren't compatible with each other.

Comment: I have customized the index.js(https://github.com/computerjazz/react-native-draggable-flatlist/releases/tag/v1.1.9) and put it locally within the application source code folder